# Calculate UTM grid convergence using UTM coordinates

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, utm, layout-manager, convergence

What would be the simplest way to arrive at a value for UTM grid convergence for a point given in UTM coordinates?

All advice I can find requires that the point be given in latitude/longitude.  For example, there's a good post on this forum here:

[Calculating grid convergence (True North to Grid North)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115531/calculating-grid-convergence-true-north-to-grid-north)

But that would first require conversion of point information from UTM to lat/lon.  That's easy to do manually using any of the many online tools available.  Coding an automated solution is also doable, though tedious.  I managed to put together an Excel spreadsheet, benefiting from guidance offered here:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-UTM-into-longitude-and-latitude-without-using-software

My particular application is in QGIS, where I'm trying to use the Expression String Builder to automatically set Print Layout > Main Properties > Map Rotation to orient the map so that up is true north.  Ideally I'd like to be able to use x(@map_extent_center)  and y(@map_extent_center) to get grid convergence at map center, then rotate the map by that amount.  The ultimate goal there is to create maps similar to USGS 7.5-minute quadrangles, to be used for orienteering in the field.

Note that I did check out the QGIS plugin Lat Lon Tools.  It includes functions for use in the Expression String Builder, but those functions convert lat/lon to UTM, not visa versa.

Comment: See this answer here?:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339161/calculating-convergence-angle-for-point-data-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

For an exhaustive mathematical discussion see Peter Osborne's "The Mercator Projections".  Osborne's material was used to create the more succinct Wikipedia article here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection#Convergence

That discussion gives convergence angle (in radians!) as

arctan( tanh(x/k₀a) * tan(y/k₀a) )

where for UTM

k₀ = 0.9996

and

a = 6378137

But that doesn't go into details about the position of x relative to the central meridian.  If we just plug in our UTM easting value, the result will be incorrect.  For UTM, x starts counting 500000 meters to the west of the central meridian.  So our equation would look more like

arctan( tanh((x-500000)/k₀a) * tan(y/k₀a) )

We have to know whether the UTM zone we're working with is in the northern or southern hemisphere because

y = northing in the north hemisphere

but

y = northing - 10,000,000 in the southern hemisphere

Note that if working in QGIS we don't have tanh(), but can substitute tanh()=sin()*cos().

arctan( sin((x-500000)/k₀a) * cos((x-500000)/k₀a) * tan(y/k₀a) )

Also, if wanting an answer in degrees instead of radians (i.e., so we can rotate our map), then we have to multiply by 180/pi()

Using the above, we can create an expression in QGIS to automatically rotate the map to true north.  The expression might look something like this:

atan(sin((x(@map_extent_center)-500000)/6375585.745)*cos((x(@map_extent_center)-500000)/6375585.745)*tan(y(@map_extent_center)/6375585.745))*180/pi()

I have used that expression with success, but in the end it has seemed more convenient to use the idea proposed by Houska in the answer here:

[Calculating convergence angle for point data in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339161/calculating-convergence-angle-for-point-data-in-qgis)

where all the math is done under the hood by QGIS, so that we don't have to worry about what hemisphere we're in or even what CRS we're using.  However, I could not get Houska's code to work as is, but had to adapt it as follows:

azimuth( make_point(x(@map_extent_center),y(@map_extent_center)),
transform(translate(transform( make_point(x(@map_extent_center),y(@map_extent_center)),@map_crs,'EPSG:4326'),0,0.1),'EPSG:4326',@map_crs))/-pi()*180