# Meridian Convergence in UTM and Gauss Kruger Projection system?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, mercator, geodesy, transverse-mercator

There are points where geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude) are known. I have calculated the UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) projection coordinates of these points and then I want to calculate the meridian convergence. I don't know the formula for meridian convergence in UTM, but I know how to calculate meridian convergence from Gauss Kruger coordinates. My question is, are the meridian convergence values calculated from UTM and Gauss Kruger coordinates the same?

Comment: Not quite an answer to your Q regarding Gauss Kruger, but for a formula for meridian convergence in UTM see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115531/calculating-grid-convergence-true-north-to-grid-north/393677