# True north/east in UTM rasters

Tags: utm, true-north

I have rasters that are in UTM projection (of various zones, depending on the location of the raster) at 10-meter pixel spacing. The rasters are, on average, 29,000 by 21,000 pixels which covers a 290km-by-210km area.

Is it the case that since: (1) the rasters are in UTM projection and; (2) the rasters cover "local" areas, I can infer that true geographic north-south direction is perfectly vertical and true geographic east-west direction is perfectly horizontal anywhere in the raster?

[Edited to state "geographic" north.]

Comment: By "true north", do you mean geographic north or grid north? If the former, no, there is a difference which increases the further from the central meridian you are.

Comment: I meant geographic north.

Do you know any reference material (bonus if it includes Python/GDAL examples) that I can look into to figure out how to determine the geographic north in my rasters?

Comment: Honestly, this is above my level. The convergence angle value would be different for every pixel in your raster.

Comment: See this post for a solution:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115531/calculating-grid-convergence-true-north-to-grid-north