# Is there a easy way to get the Grid convergence in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, angular, convergence

Is there an easy way to get the angular difference between Grid North & True North in QGIS?

This is how I do it:

1. Make a map in print composer
2. Set the map CRS to whatever "WGS 84 / UTM zone" I need the grid convergence for.
3. Place a North Arrow & synch it with map to True North.
4. The Degrees of rotation on the image is my angular difference between TN and GN.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to have one question.

Comment: You can calculate it directly - for example, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115531/calculating-grid-convergence-true-north-to-grid-north

Comment: @Vince -- This is clearly *one* question!

Comment: @MartinF Only after editing

Comment: @MartinF Because it was a welcome message