# Finding the shortest distance between a point and a line

Tags: geolocation, mathematics

I read and understood the following GIS question and the accepted answer,

[calculating-the-distance-between-a-point-and-a-virtual-line-of-two-lat-lngs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11409/calculating-the-distance-between-a-point-and-a-virtual-line-of-two-lat-lngs)

I can return the value in the `ShortestLength` variable (required for my project).

**My question is: what is the measurement of this variable (ie.) Is it in kilometer or meter or do I have to convert it using the diameter of the earth?**

I'm not sure. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: If you are in a projected coordinate system, it is going to be in the same units used for that coordinate system (e.g. if the units are meters than the measurement will be in meters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question and its answer correctly, you would need to use the earth's radius to get from the answer in that question to a measurement in kilometers etc.

See [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) page, in particular the sections on calculating the **Bearing** and **Cross-track distance**

Comment: I found the distance between (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) which gave the perpendicular distance.