# How to calculate the shortest geographical distance between a line and a point?

Tags: distance, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to calculate the shortest distance between a line (described as a pair of [lat, long]s) and a point (lat, long) accurately.
I've read many Wikipedia pages, but I'm new to the topic. I've read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11409/calculating-the-distance-between-a-point-and-a-virtual-line-of-two-lat-lngs) question, but I'm still confused, because they say that

> Literally, a "straight line" will pass beneath the earth's surface.

while my line lies on the surface of the Earth. How can I calculate this?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any software, just need this calculation in a project. (A Java project, if it matters.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know postgis, you can create the shortest line between two geometries : http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_ShortestLine.html.
Then you can calculate the length with :http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Length.html

If you dont need to create the line : st_distance should be enough : http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Distance.html

Comment: I'd rather like to compute it by myself, without Postgis. But thanks, anyway!

Comment: My solution is given in http://sourceforge.net/p/geographiclib/discussion/1026621/thread/21aaff9f/#8a93 this uses C++.  However the solution can be implemented in Java too, since the needed functions are in the Java version of GeographicLib